# Centralized system information

Tags: linux, documentation

Does anyone know of a software capable of keeping track of Linux/UNIX systems configurations centralized on a server? Possibly with a web GUI and history capabilities?

I am looking for something that is capable of listing filesystems, crontabs, installed software, etc.

To be more specific... I'd like to be able to define a given command set (df, crontab -l, uname -a, etc.) to be executed on remotes hosts, get the output of the commands and have them in an history. I'd like it to be something resembling a document management system but for UNIX/Linux system infos.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a software capable of keeping track of Linux/UNIX systems configurations centralized on a server? Possibly with a web gui and history capabilities?

There are probably two ways of approaching this particular question, and it depends on exactly what you're asking.

If you have an existing fleet of systems and you are looking for a way to keep track of what you own, when it was purchased, who is responsible for it, when the warranty expires, etc, then you are probably looking for "asset management" software.  A search for that will give you lots of relevant results.

If you are looking for a way to manage the software configuration across a number of servers, then you are probably asking about "configuration management".  In this space, tools like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [puppet](https://puppet.com/), [chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), and others will let you deploy software and configurations from a central location -- often maintained using version control software such as git -- across a few systems or across thousands of systems.

All of the above provide both CLI tools as well as advanced web-based management interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Spacewalk. It comes with a lot of centralized Administration tools which can help you in various tasks.

[Red Hat SpaceWalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/)